# What's the differences between .dll , .lib, .h files?

Tags: c++, windows, dll, header-files

Why in a project should I include some *.lib, .h or some other files? And what are these things used for?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

- `.h`: header file, its a source file containing declarations (as opposed to .cpp, .cxx, etc. containing implementations),
- `.lib`: static library may contain code or just links to a dynamic library. Either way it's compiled code that you link with your program. The static library is included in your .exe at link time.
- `.dll`: dynamic library. Just like a static one but you need to deploy it with your .exe file because it's loaded at run time.

Comment: It should be noted that there is also something which is called "Import Library" check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3573475/how-does-the-import-library-work-details

Answer (score 31):

- **H** Declares the interface to a library - including functions, structures, and constants. Written in the C language.
- **LIB** Either declares the binary interface to a dynamic library (DLL) *or* contains the binary code of a library.
- **DLL** A dynamic library - your application shares these with the system or you use them to keep your code base organized.
- **DEF** A textual description of functions exported by a DLL.

Answer (score -6):

*.dlb is similar to static library.