# Where do I input DLL dependencies in Visual Studio C++ project?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, dll

I am converting some Qt project files (.pro)  that run on Linux and Mac into Visual Studio project files (.vcproj) The Qt Visual Studio add-in converted everything fine except the DLL dependencies. Where do I put these in Visual Studio 2008?

If I put the DLLs in Configuration Properties > Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies, I get:

```
fatal error LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0xABC
```

Where do dynamically-linked dependencies go?

Comment: It should be noted that there is also something which is called "Import Library" check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3573475/how-does-the-import-library-work-details

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You might want to check [what’s the differences between .dll , .lib, .h files ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778111/whats-the-differences-between-dll-lib-h-files).

You need to specify the corresponding .lib file at link time. not the dll.

Comment: As a novice Visual Studio and MS Windows developer, I found this answer a bit confusing. To clarify my confusion I needed this detail: indeed, to dynamically link a library (dll) the linker needs a lib file (lib). The dll and lib file are related and the lib file tells the linker something about the dll. This is _not_ the way things work on Unix OSes, and I found it confusing. In some cases (static linking) the lib file has the compiled code, but in the case of dlls, it does not.

Answer (score 11):

Project Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies

In that field put xxxx.lib for whatever library you need.