# How does the Import Library work? Details?

Tags: c++, c, windows, visual-c++

I know this may seem quite basic to geeks. But I want to make it crystal clear.

When I want to use a Win32 DLL, usually I just call the APIs like LoadLibrary() and GetProcAdderss(). But recently, I am developing with DirectX9, and I need to add *d3d9.lib*, *d3dx9.lib*, etc files.

I have heard enough that LIB is for static linking and DLL is for dynamic linking.

So my current understanding is that LIB contains the implementation of the methods and is statically linked at link time as part of the final EXE file. While DLL is dynamic loaded at runtime and is not part of the final EXE file.

But sometimes, there're some LIB files **coming with** the DLL files, so:

- What are these LIB files for?
- How do they achieve what they are meant for?
- Is there any tools that can let me inspect the internals of these LIB files?

### Update 1

After checking wikipedia, I remember that these LIB files are called [import library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic-link_library#Import_libraries).
But I am wondering how it works with my main application and the DLLs to be dynamically loaded.

### Update 2

Just as RBerteig said, there're some stub code in the LIB files born with the DLLs. So the calling sequence should be like this:

My main application  --> stub in the LIB  --> real target DLL

So what information should be contained in these LIBs? I could think of the following:

- The LIB file should contain the fullpath of the corresponding DLL; So the DLL could be loaded by the runtime.
- The relative address (or file offset?) of each DLL export method's entry point should be encoded in the stub; So correct jumps/method calls could be made.

Am I right on this? Is there something more?

**BTW: Is there any tool that can inspect an import library? If I can see it, there'll be no more doubts.**

Comment: I see that no one addressed the last part of your question, which regards tools that can inspect an import library. With Visual C++, there are at least two ways to do it: `lib /list xxx.lib` and `link /dump /linkermember xxx.lib`. See [this Stack Overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6402586/know-if-lib-is-static-or-import).

Comment: Also, `dumpbin -headers xxx.lib` provides some more detailed information, compared to the `lib` and `link` utilities.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

Linking to a DLL file can occur *implicitly* at <strike>compile</strike> link time, or *explicitly* at run time. Either way, the DLL ends up loaded into the processes memory space, and all of its exported entry points are available to the application.

If used explicitly at run time, you use `LoadLibrary()` and `GetProcAddress()` to manually load the DLL and get pointers to the functions you need to call.

If linked implicitly when the program is built, then stubs for each DLL export used by the program get linked in to the program from an import library, and those stubs get updated as the EXE and the DLL are loaded when the process launches. (Yes, I've simplified more than a little here...)

Those stubs need to come from somewhere, and in the Microsoft tool chain they come from a special form of .LIB file called an *import library*. The required .LIB is usually built at the same time as the DLL, and contains a stub for each function exported from the DLL.

Confusingly, a static version of the same library would also be shipped as a .LIB file. There is no trivial way to tell them apart, except that LIBs that are import libraries for DLLs will usually be smaller (often much smaller) than the matching static LIB would be.

If you use the GCC toolchain, incidentally, you don't actually need import libraries to match your DLLs. The version of the Gnu linker ported to Windows understands DLLs directly, and can synthesize most any required stubs on the fly.

#### Update

If you just can't resist knowing where all the nuts and bolts really are and what is really going on, there is always something at MSDN to help. Matt Pietrek's article [**An In-Depth Look into the Win32 Portable Executable File Format**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301805.aspx) is a very complete overview of the format of the EXE file and how it gets loaded and run. Its even been updated to cover .NET and more since it originally appeared in MSDN Magazine ca. 2002.

Also, it can be helpful to know how to learn exactly what DLLs are used by a program. The tool for that is Dependency Walker, aka depends.exe. A version of it is included with Visual Studio, but the latest version is available from its author at http://www.dependencywalker.com/. It can identify all of the DLLs that were specified at link time (both early load and delay load) and it can also run the program and watch for any additional DLLs it loads at run time.

#### Update 2

I've reworded some of the earlier text to clarify it on re-reading, and to use the terms of art *implicit* and *explicit linking* for consistency with MSDN.

So, we have three ways that library functions might be made available to be used by a program. The obvious follow up question is then: "How to I choose which way?"

Static linking is how the bulk of the program itself is linked. All of your object files are listed, and get collected together in to the EXE file by the linker. Along the way, the linker takes care of minor chores like fixing up references to global symbols so that your modules can call each other's functions. Libraries can also be statically linked. The object files that make up the library are collected together by a librarian in a .LIB file which the linker searches for modules containing symbols that are needed. One effect of static linking is that only those modules from the library that are used by the program are linked to it; other modules are ignored. For instance, the traditional C math library includes many trigonometry functions. But if you link against it and use `cos()`, you don't end up with a copy of the code for `sin()` or `tan()` unless you also called those functions. For large libraries with a rich set of features, this selective inclusion of modules is important. On many platforms such as embedded systems, the total size of code available for use in the library can be large compared to the space available to store an executable in the device. Without selective inclusion, it would be harder to manage the details of building programs for those platforms.

However, having a copy of the *same* library in every program running creates a burden on a system that normally runs lots of processes. With the right kind of virtual memory system, pages of memory that have identical content need only exist once in the system, but can be used by many processes. This creates a benefit for increasing the chances that the pages containing code are likely to be identical to some page in as many other running processes as possible. But, if programs statically link to the runtime library, then each has a different mix of functions each laid out in that processes memory map at different locations, and there aren't many sharable code pages unless it is a program that all by itself is run in more than process. So the idea of a DLL gained another, major, advantage.

A DLL for a library contains all of its functions, ready for use by any client program. If many programs load that DLL, they can all share its code pages. Everybody wins. (Well, until you update a DLL with new version, but that isn't part of this story. Google DLL Hell for that side of the tale.)

So the first big choice to make when planning a new project is between dynamic and static linkage. With static linkage, you have fewer files to install, and you are immune from third parties updating a DLL you use. However, your program is larger, and it isn't quite as good citizen of the Windows ecosystem. With dynamic linkage, you have more files to install, you might have issues with a third party updating a DLL you use, but you are generally being friendlier to other processes on the system.

A big advantage of a DLL is that it can be loaded and used without recompiling or even relinking the main program. This can allow a third party library provider (think Microsoft and the C runtime, for example) to fix a bug in their library and distribute it. Once an end user installs the updated DLL, they immediately get the benefit of that bug fix in all programs that use that DLL. (Unless it breaks things. See DLL Hell.)

The other advantage comes from the distinction between implicit and explicit loading. If you go to the extra effort of explicit loading, then the DLL might not even have existed when the program was written and published. This allows for extension mechanisms that can discover and load plugins, for instance.

Comment: Deleting my post and upvoting this, because you explain things a way better than I do ;) Nice answer.

Comment: @ereOn, you reply is also good. I read it and appreciated it.

Comment: @smwikipedia: Is this ironic ? Because my answer didn't explain anything. I was on my way of editing it to add more information when I saw RBerteig's one.

Comment: @ereOn, you didn't really *need* to delete your answer. There's lots of room at SO for different approaches to explaining the same concepts. Some work better than others for specific readers...

Comment: @ereOn, no, it's not ironic. What you said  reminds me of something which I have long taken for grated.

Comment: @RBerteig: You must be right. But in this case, trust me, my answer brought nothing to the pot. So if I can reduce the noise and vote for a good answer, it is just as fine.

Comment: @RBerteig: Thanks for your great answer. Just a little correction, according to here(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yd93633.aspx), there're 2 types of dynamic linking to a DLL, *load-time implicit linking* and *run-time explicit linking*. No *compile-time linking*. Now I am wondering what's the difference between traditional *Static Linking* (linking to a \*.lib file that contains the full implementation) and *Load-Time dynamic linking* to a DLL (through a import library)?

Comment: Continue: What're the pros and cons of *Static Linking* and *Load-Time dynamic linking*? It seems that these 2 approaches both load all the necessary files into the address space at the start of a process. Why do we need 2 of them?  Thanks.

Comment: @smwikipedia, My answer is talking about the same distinction made in the MSDN article you cite, I just didn't use the same words. I'll elaborate in-answer on the static v. dynamic part.

Comment: @RBerteig the link to Matt Pietrek's article is not working can you fix it please?

Comment: @ameen, Sorry, it appears that MSDN has disappeared the article. Even their own search engine returns off-topic hits. In their defense, it was written in 2002, but that is a pretty thin excuse. Google turns up copies at random sites in PDF, but nothing official.

Comment: you can maybe use a tool like "objdump" to peek inside a .lib file and figure out whether it is an import library or a true static library. on Linux when cross compiling to a Windows target, it is possible to run 'ar'  or 'nm' on the .a files (mingw version of .lib files) and note that the import libs have generic .o file names and no code (just a 'jmp' instruction), while the static libs have lots of functions and code inside.

Comment: Small correction: You can also *implicitly* link at run-time. [Linker Support for Delay-Loaded DLLs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/151kt790.aspx) explains this in detail. This is helpful if you want to dynamically change the DLL search path, or gracefully handle import resolution failure (to support new OS features, but still run on older versions, for example).

Comment: @ameen: If in doubt, ask the [Wayback Machine](https://archive.org/web/). It has a snapshot of the article you are looking for: [An In-Depth Look into the Win32 Portable Executable File Format](https://web.archive.org/web/20080828195258/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301805.aspx) (arbitrarily picked a snapshot from 2008).

Comment: You can distinguish import an lib from a static lib. Run `dumpbin /symbols foo.lib|find "IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR"`. An import lib has `__IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR_FOO` as well as `__NULL_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR` in the symbols table.

Answer (score 7):

These .LIB import library files are used in the following project property, `Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies`, when building a bunch of dll's that need additional information at link time which is supplied by the import library .LIB files. In the example below to not get linker errors I need to reference to dll's A,B,C, and D through their lib files. (note for the linker to find these files you may need to include their deployment path in `Linker->General->Additional Library Directories` else you will get a build error about being unable to find any of the provided lib files.)

[image: Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies]

If your solution is building all dynamic libraries you may have been able to avoid this explicit dependency specification by relying instead on the reference flags exposed under the `Common Properties->Framework and References` dialog. These flags appear to automatically do the linking on your behalf using the *.lib files.
[image: Framework and References]

This however is as it says a *Common* Properties, which is not configuration or platform specific. If you need to support a mixed build scenario as in our application we had a build configuration to render a static build and a special configuration that built a constrained build of a subset of assemblies that were deployed as dynamic libraries. I had used the `Use Library Dependency Inputs`  and `Link Library Dependencies` flags set to true under various cases to get things to build and later realizing to simplify things but when introducing my code to the static builds I introduced a ton of linker warnings and the build was incredibly slow for the static builds. I wound up introducing a bunch of these sort of warnings...

```
warning LNK4006: "bool __cdecl XXX::YYY() already defined in CoreLibrary.lib(JSource.obj); second definition ignored  D.lib(JSource.obj)
```

And I wound up using the manual specification of `Additional Dependencies` to satisfy the linker for the dynamic builds while keeping the static builders happy by not using a common property that slowed them down. When I deploy the dynamic subset build I only deploy the dll files as these lib files are only used at link time, not at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some related MSDN topics to answer my question:

[Linking an Executable to a DLL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yd93633.aspx)

[Linking Implicitly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14wsce5.aspx)

[Determining Which Linking Method to Use](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/253b8k2c.aspx)

[Building an Import Library and Export File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b9xe492.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

There are three kinds of libraries: static, shared and dynamically loaded libraries.

The static libraries are linked with the code at the linking phase, so they are actually in the executable, unlike the shared library, which has only stubs (symbols) to look for in the shared library file, which is loaded at run time before the main function gets called.

The dynamically loaded ones are much like the shared libraries, except they are loaded when and if the need arises by the code you've written.

Comment: @Thanks zacsek. But I am not sure about your statement about shared library.

Comment: @smwikipedia: Linux has them, I use them, so they most definitely exist. Also read: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_(computing)

Comment: Its a subtle difference. Shared and dynamic libraries are both DLL files. The distinction is when they are loaded. Shared libraries are loaded by the OS along with the EXE. Dynamic libraries are loaded by code calling `LoadLibrary()` and the related APIs.

Comment: I read from [1] that DLL is Microsoft's implementation of Shared Library concept. [1]:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic-link_library#Import_libraries

Comment: I disagree that it is a subtle difference, from the programming view it makes a huge difference whether the shared library is dinamically loaded or not (if it's dinamically loaded, then you have to add boilerplate code to access functions).

Comment: Yes, but there are still a variety of patterns for their use that serve different purposes. Binding a DLL (or .so) to an executable so that it is implicitly loaded when the program is launched is a good way to allow lots of programs to share common code pages, as for the C runtime library in MSVCRT.DLL. Loading a DLL (or .so) into a running process is one way to implement plugins and extensions that might only be loaded because the files are placed in the correct folder. Sometimes the latter use case is called "dynamic" to distinguish it from the former.

Comment: @zacsek: I'm particularly interested in how those stubs work. Can you elaborate some more on them?

Answer (score 1):

In my mind, there are two method to link dll to exe.

1. Use dll and the import library (.lib file) implicitly
2. Use functions like loadlibrary() explicitly

Comment: Hmm, and then I come and drop a comment suggesting to use the import library (1) for delay-loading, which technically employs method 2. What now?