# know if .lib is static or import

Tags: c++, c, windows, dll

I have `.lib` file compiled from C code. How I know if this self-contained static library or just an import lib and DLL will be needed at runtime? Is there some `dumpbin` option I'm missing?

Comment: Strange question.  If you don't have the DLL then you can only cross your fingers.

Comment: Normally you would read the documentation. If you don't have documentation and don't know the provenance of the .lib then you should think twice about using it.

Comment: Sadly, many libraries come with "getting started" or "readme" files that are out of date, and some mysterious hidden option to configure if it's building static or dynamic. This gets worse when it's not even a library I want, but one needed by a library that I want.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Use the lib command. If it's static, lib will show you a pile of .obj files inside. Not so if it's an implib.

```
lib /list foo.lib
```

will do it.

Also see:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/managing-a-library

Comment: can you suggest which option(s) to give `lib` to perform this? I can't understand from its doc

Comment: @zaharpopov MSDN docs have been revamped since the release of Windows 8.1. Please check.

Comment: There seems to be a similar way. Open the lib file with 7zip. If it's an imort lib, it would contain *.dll files. Otherwise, it would contain *.obj files, maybe in a folder.

Comment: Your answer, in my opinion, is the better one. Thank you, i will adapt to your method. Before, I did it slightly differently: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8019464/static-library-v-s-import-library-on-windows-platform/51861571#51861571 but your `lib` method is the better method.

Comment: Trying this today on Windows 10, I got `'lib' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: this is bad answer, please also let other know how to install `lib` command, since this command is not default avaible on any platform.

Comment: Windows is only one platform, and this question is about windows, and the lib command comes with the windows SDK, which you need to have to do any development.

Comment: If you have Visual Studio installed, there is a lib.exe there, as well. If you install the Community edition, 2019, it will be somewhere like "C:\Program Files (x86)\ Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\##.##.#####\bin\Hostx64\x64\". The "##.##.#####" are a bunch of numbers, which I'm not sure what are... maybe a specific version? Plus, if you need the executable for 32 bit windows there are other folders there as well (e.g. Hostx32)

Comment: There is _no_ dichotomy between static and import libs. A lib can just as well contain both: code and import descriptors. It's as easy as `lib /out:combined.lib static.lib implib.lib` to create one or reverse the process by doing `lib /remove:implib.dll combined.lib` (assuming `implib.dll` to be the DLL name whose import descriptors we initially merged). Last but not least invoking `lib.exe` == `link.exe /lib`.

Comment: So the claim that an import lib cannot contain object files may technically be true, but if you are looking at a combined lib, you're still none the wiser.

Answer (score 4):

Look in its accompanying header files ,if the function are 'decorated' with `__declspec(dllimport)` that it's an import library. Or look for an accompanying .def file ,that also tells you that it's an import library.

Comment: `__declspec(dllimport)` is a thing of Microsoft compiler only afaik.

Comment: Meanwhile other compiler support this, mostly to stay compatible to some extent with what `cl.exe` does. However, looking into a header file isn't useful advice. It assumes there is a header (in addition to the lib we're looking at), it assumes the header contains these, but those could be hidden behind an API -- which could be as obvious as `DECLSPEC_IMPORT` or as innocuous as `POLARITY` or `FOOBAR_API` or something as counterintuitive as `DLLEXP`. Aside from that no header is needed to create or process import libs.