# A static library vs. an import library on the Windows platform

Tags: windows, visual-c++, static-libraries

How could I tell one .lib file is a static library vs. an import library for a DLL file? Is there a tool or command that could do this?

The second question is: How could I check the dependencies of a static library? I mean, how could I know which DLL files are included in this static library?

Comment: That information will be supplied with the .lib file

Comment: If you have no clue like this then you do *not* want to use the library.  Contact the owner of the code and ask about support options.

Comment: Note that static library and import library are just two extrema in the spectrum. You can also have a mixed static/import library.

Comment: Re your second question: do you mean which DLLs are included in the static library, or which DLLs the static library depends on?

Answer (score 6):

An import library will add a DLL dependency to your program. Your program won't start, if you don't have the DLL. (You may use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to get the names of the DLL's of your program depend on.)

As far as I know, static libraries do not have dependencies. They are linked into the program, and only linker errors will tell you if that particular library depends on another library. (At least in GCC; I don't know want is the behaviors of the MS tools.)

Comment: To expand on this: link the static library with a trivial program, and then use Dependency Walker to look for any new DLL dependencies.

Comment: static libraries do typically have DLL dependencies for at least the basic system libraries (ntdll.dll, etc.) and may also have dependencies for the language runtime, e.g., msvcrt.dll.

Answer (score 6):

Given only a *wtf.lib* file, the question is to determine whether this library file is a *static library* or an *import library*. The current way I do this is (via a combination of DOS prompt and a [Cygwin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin) Bash shell).

In a DOS prompt, this is needed to correctly run *dumpbin.exe*:

`dumpbin -all wtf.lib > wtf.lib.txt`

Then, in the Cygwin shell:

`grep 'Archive member name' wtf.lib.txt`

If the output of `grep` spits out a DLL filename, then `wtf.lib` is an *import library*. Else, it is a stand-alone *static library*.

Comment: I have to vow and admit to the more superior answer found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6402586/know-if-lib-is-static-or-import

Comment: Unfortunately this answer completely neglects the possibility of bundling/combining static and import libs into a single `.lib` file. Instead you proclaim a dichotomy that doesn't exist. It shouldn't be a surprise that this is possible and I have seen at least one vendor supplying such a `.lib`. You can create them yourself with `lib /out:combined.lib staticlib.lib implib.lib` and you can also take them apart again with `lib /remove:implib.dll combined.lib` (note that we have to give the DLL name for the `/remove` argument).