# Why is the dynamic library not selected despite -Wl,-Bdynamic?

Tags: gcc, ld, mingw-w64

I am using 3rd party libraries to build my executable. More specifically I have in `./extern/bin/win64`

```
libfoo.dll
libfoo.dll.a
libbar.dll
```

Despite its name, it looks like `libfoo.dll.a` **isn't really an import library**, but rather an archive (static library). After scratching my head for some time, I came to this conclusion by looking at the output of `lib /list libfoo.dll.a` (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6403559/8543838)) which gives me a bunch of .o files.

The command line I'm using to build my executable is always the same:

```
g++ -std=c++14 test.cpp -I./extern/include -L./extern/bin/win64 -lbaz -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -Wl,-Bstatic -lstdc++ -lpthread -Wl,-Bdynamic -lfoo -lbar -s -o test.exe
```

My understanding is that the final `-Wl,-Bdynamic` gives preference to dynamic linkage but doesn't insist on dynamic linkage. The linker should still be happy if only the static version of a library exist, but it should pick the dynamic version when both the static and the dynamic version exist. Correct ?

Now here is the part that puzzles me a little bit. If, in `./extern/bin/win64`, I only keep `libbar.dll` and:

1. `libfoo.dll`   then the executable has dependencies on `libfoo.dll` and `libbar.dll` (expected: dynamic linkage to `libfoo` is the only option)
2. `libfoo.dll.a` then the executable has a dependency  on `libbar.dll` only (expected: static linkage  to `libfoo` is the only option)
3. Both `libfoo.dll` and `libfoo.dll.a` then the executable has a dependency  on `libbar.dll` only (surprising: static linkage seems to have been used but dynamic linkage was supposed to be preferred)

Does anyone have a theory to explain #3 ? Are my expectations incorrect ?

**[Edit]** As an extension to #3, I have also found that if I separate `libfoo.dll` and `libfoo.dll.a` into different folders, then the first folder to appear on the command line following `-L` determines which version of the library is selected. Again `-Wl,-Bdynamic` does not seem to have the expected effect....

PS: if anyone wants to have a detailed inspection of the libraries, they're distributed with Matlab, located in `extern\bin\win64` as discussed. For completeness, the source code for my example can be found [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/test-your-build-environment.html) but is this probably not relevant. Also using gcc 6.3 from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/6.3.0/threads-posix/seh/x86_64-6.3.0-release-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev2.7z/download).

Comment: In `ld` point of view, it did choose the dynamic linking option in #3. Because it expects the `.dll.a` file to be a dynamic linker library, not a static one (which should be `.a`).

Comment: You're absolutely right ;-) I simply renamed the `.dll.a` file as `.a` and then suddenly everything behaved as expected ! This made me realize that having the correct file name extensions is critical (although in this specific example, I should blame it on the 3rd party who provides the libraries) - I wrongly assumed that `ld` was actually looking at the content of the libraries to find out if static linkage or dynamic linkage would be used.

Comment: Let me rephrase slightly.
After renaming the .dll.a file as .a, everything behaves as expected when using my windows **native** toolchain ('as expected' in the sense that in #3, the executable has a dependency on both `libfoo.dll` and `libbar.dll`).
However, when using my windows **cross-compilation** toolchain (runs on Linux), I still get the same behavior as before (the executable has a dependency on `libbar.dll` only).
But I also found that if I change the command line to `-llibfoo -llibbar` then I do get dynamic linking. Can anyone make sense of that ??

Comment: The section 'direct linking to a DLL' in the [win32 ld documentation](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/WIN32.html#WIN32) is very informative. I still cannot explain the behavior seen with my windows cross-compilation toolchain though.

Comment: Last but not least, I have found that `libfoo.dll.a` actually seems to be some kind of hybrid (not sure what to call it) in the sense that it is **both** an archive (`lib /list libfoo.dll.a` gives me a bunch of .o files) and an import library (`link /dump /linkermember libfoo.dll.a` gives me a bunch of exported functions - Thanks to Alan in [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3573475/how-does-the-import-library-work-details)). It could well be the cause of all this confusion. Has anybody seen anything like this before ?

Comment: `link /dump /linkermember` gives you all functions that the linker can use, but that doesn't necessarily mean that they were exported in the dll sense.

Comment: @ssbssa: thanks for the clarification ! As a sanity check I tried using `link /dump /linkermember` on a proper archive (static library) and realised it was still giving me a bunch of names.... In the end I found that `dumpbin /symbols /exports libfoo.dll.a` removed any ambiguity. It's not very readable (to me) but clearly shows what I suspected: both a bunch of static functions, and a bunch of exported functions.