I don’t understand what is causing dll creation
I use 3 libraries, I connected all of them using vcpkg using static, compile in Release/MT, but I don't understand why 2 of them are created dynamically:
libcrypto-3-x64.dll and ssh.dll
Through DependencyWalker, I saw that the .exe file itself directly requires only ssh.dll, and ssh.dll requires libcrypto-3-x64.dll.
There are no problems with jsoncpp.lib.
I added them to the project accordingly:
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\vcpkg\packages\openssl_x64-windows-static\lib;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\vcpkg\packages\libssh_x64-windows-static\lib;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\vcpkg\packages\jsoncpp_x64-windows-static\lib"

I also added the corresponding libraries to the list of additional dependencies:
"$(CoreLibraryDependencies);%(AdditionalDependencies)Crypt32.lib;ws2_32.lib;ssh.lib;jsoncpp.lib;libcrypto.lib"

But, the thing is that libcrypto.lib needs other Windows libraries, which I also include (without specifying the path to them):
Crypt32.lib;ws2_32.lib

Also I use similar include and pragma settings:
#include <Windows.h>
#include <wincrypt.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>

#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <libssh/sftp.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Crypt32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "jsoncpp.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "libcrypto.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "ssh.lib")

Maybe it's a matter of connecting .h header files (openssl/evp.h, libssh/sftp.h, fcntl.h) from libssh and openssl?
I understand that the problem is most likely in Crypt32.lib and
ws2_32.lib, but I'm new and don’t understand how to fix it. I couldn’t find a way on the Internet to connect these two libraries statically. Of course, I could spend time myself and find a solution, but I already spent all day understanding static compilation and therefore I ask for your help.
What can I add? The problem is only with ssh.lib, there are no problems with libcrypto.lib (checked). Most likely ssh.lib cannot be made static, which is very sad. But if anyone has any ideas, I will be glad.

Many .lib files don't contain a full implementation, just instructions for how to call the function from the DLL.  I can't tell you if that's the case specifically here.

I connected all of them using vcpkg using static Are you sure you used the static triplets like: https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/blob/master/triplets/x64-windows-static.cmake ? If you are not getting static libraries with one of the static triplets could be a bug with that port or maybe it doesn't support static. Not all libraries can be built as static.

@drescherjm Yes, I used vcpkg install libssh:x64-windows-static and vcpkg install openssl:x64-windows-static and I can't figure out what the problem is

This may help test if the .lib is an import library or static library: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6402586/know-if-lib-is-static-or-import

@drescherjm
I honestly don't understand what's going on. I checked ssh.lib as they wrote in the article - the library is completely static, it has its own .obj and no .dll, but at the same time it creates libcrypto-3-x64.dll (the removal of which does not affect the operation of the program!)

What about libcrypto.lib? My thoughts were either one of these were import libraries or perhaps your library paths were pulling in the libs from a different location.

@drescherjm It is also static. I checked my code and noticed that when I remove ssh.lib (and the associated code block with it), the dll file is not created. There are no such problems with libcrypto.lib, it works and does not create dll files.

The thing turned out to be that OpenSSL includes two libraries: in addition to libcrypto.lib, there is also libssl.lib, which is used by ssh.lib. I added libssl.lib to the list of libraries and everything became normal
