# Installing GLUT fails due to missing foreign library - ghc7.8

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal

I tried `cabal install GLUT` which gave the following:

```
Setup: Missing dependency on a foreign library:
* Missing C library: glut32
This problem can usually be solved by installing the system package that
provides this library (you may need the "-dev" version). If the library is
already installed but in a non-standard location then you can use the flags
--extra-include-dirs= and --extra-lib-dirs= to specify where it is.
```

So I thought, ok, lets get the sources and point cabal to the directories. I first tried [freeglut](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/index.php#download) and then the following

```
cabal install GLUT --extra-include-dirs="<path to freeglut>\include" 
                   --extra-lib-dirs="<path to freeglut>\src"
```

Same thing, so I thought maybe it doesn't work with freeglut, and got [glut](http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/):

```
cabal install GLUT --extra-include-dirs="<path to glut>\include" 
                   --extra-lib-dirs="<path to glut>\lib"
```

When this doesn't work, I try to download the source and `cabal install` inside the directory, then `runghc Setup configure`. Then thinking that there is some parse error of the paths, I try every possible way of writing a file path known to man; quotes, no quotes, backslashes, double backslashes, forward slashes, and every combination of the above. I even placed all the files on my `PATH` in hopes it would find them. All other options exhausted, I proceeded to sacrifice a goat to satan, but still no dice.

The question is, what do I have to do to convince `ghc` to find this library? (this is windows 7)

Comment: Most likely, you need to install a binary version of glut/freeglut, then point `--extra-lib-dirs` to the path where `glut32.dll` is located.

Comment: @JohnL `glut32.dll` is on `PATH` so it should find it but I tried it anyways and the result is as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the `libglut32.a` [import library](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/CreateImportLibraries) accessible to the compiler (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3573527/242169) for information about what import libraries are). Just copy it under `$GHCDIR/mingw/lib`. Alternatively, try the [Haskell Platform installer](http://www.haskell.org/platform/windows.html), which ships with a pre-compiled version of the GLUT bindings.