# How do import libraries work and why doesn't MinGW need them?

Tags: c++, c, windows, dll, linker

I looked at this page: [An In-Depth Look into the Win32 Portable Executable File Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301805.aspx)

It explains that the linker needs an import library because the compiler can't distinguish between normal function calls and API-function calls. But they say also that __declspec(dllimport) specifies a function call to be an API-Call so the linker links against `__imp_[function-name]`. **But** with this keyword the compiler should know that this is a call to an API-Function.

Why does the linker still need an import library? The compiler could mark this symbol as imported by prepending `__imp_` to the function name and could make a call to a function pointer (which is an unresolved symbol yet) and the linker could replace this symbol (because it sees that this an API call) with the IAT entry's address.

And why can the MinGW-linker use "MinGW-DLLs" directly but the Visual-Studio linker needs an import library?

As I read the post some other questions were also raised. How does the "dlltool (or linker)" (whichever creates the import library) know the location of an IAT entry before linkage with the final executable has been done? I thought the IAT entries would be constructed at link-time with the final executable. The post said, that every API-Call has a fixed position in the IAT table, never-mind how many DLLs will be linked. I cannot imagine how that could be achieved.

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3573527/1881610) answers most of your questions.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is possible to link to DLL without an import library as MinGW clearly demonstrates. Hence the question is why MSVC decided to omit this feature.

The reasons are primarily historic.

Back then in 1983 when Windows came around and DLLs were designed there were many toolchains (compilers, linkers) from different vendors. Going out asking the vendors to implement support for linking "DLLs" for a minority OS was clearly not an option.

So they made a decision to write a tool to generate a library everyone and their dog could link against even if a linker had absolutely no idea about DLLs.

Besides, import libraries offer some features that were vital 3 decades ago but are next to obsolete now. First is the ability to import a symbol by ordinal — i.e. DLL has an option to offer no names at all only a list of addresses; the ordinal is an index in this list. Made sence when the amount of RAM was severely limited.

Second is the support for different name mangling schemes. Even in C there is a name mangling scheme, for instance FooBar may become _FooBar@4 (it depends on the platform and the calling convention). It made perfect sense for a DLL to export "FooBar" on every supported platform for consistency (and it makes the life of GetProcAddress() user easier). Import library implements the mapping from _FooBar@4 to FooBar.

This is based on the blog ([1](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20091013-00/?p=16403), [2](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20091012-00/?p=16413)) of  Raimond Chen, the man who was involved in Windows development from the very beginning.

Comment: where can i find more details about what exactly is contained in import library and how it works in link time, load time and run time?

Comment: Chen: "The .dll doesn’t contain all the information the linker needs"... " If I have a program (myprogram.c) that calls some C function `void someFunction(int)` defined in some dynamic library a.dll, wouldn't the compiler when compiling myprogram.c -> myprogram.obj  generate some placeholder `someFunction` in myprogram.obj that would match a symbol in a.dll like it would if a.dll were a static library (a.lib) instead? Why can't dlls be linked directly like .lib or .obj files? Does the PE format just not support this?

Comment: Also, it seems like there are exported symbols in a dll file, if I do `dumpbin /exports someDll.dll` I get a lot of entries, and it seems like the symbols (names) of the functions match up with the ones in the import library file; if the dll has this information, why do I still need a lib? Is VS just not programmed to load DLLs and parse this information?