# Import Library benefit

Tags: dll, shared-libraries, static-libraries, dynamic-linking, dynamic-library

I understand pros and cons of static and dynamic linking. But what is the benefit of [Import Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3573475/how-does-the-import-library-work-details)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As it is stated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39421868/1616488) answer import library (a.k.a. stub library) is useful when one wants to link executable dynamically but do not want to mess with LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress functions.