# after conda install boost, what is the difference between libboost_python.lib and boost_python.lib

Tags: python, anaconda, libraries, conda, boost-python

After installing anaconda3 5.2 I install boost with conda install boost.

In C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\lib there are two sets of libraries for boost.

boost_python36-vc140-mt-x64-1_67.lib (177 KB)

libboost_python36-vc140-mt-x64-1_67.lib (5576 KB)

what is the difference between these? Is one static and one dynamic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer this link for naming understanding of those libraries.

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#library-naming

The one started with "lib" is

> Prefix: except on Microsoft Windows, every Boost library name begins
>   with this string. On Windows, only ordinary static libraries use the
>   lib prefix; import libraries and DLLs do not.

So it is a static library (libboost_python36-vc140-mt-x64-1_67.lib).

The other one is not with lib prefix, is import library (boost_python36-vc140-mt-x64-1_67.lib ).

Here is a good explanation about import library .

[How does the Import Library work? Details?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3573475/how-does-the-import-library-work-details)