# C++ dll and name mangling issue

Tags: c++, dll, name-mangling

I am trying out a simple test DLL project. Under my solution, I have two projects - first C++ Dll (library) and second C++ exe (driver). Below I've attached a snapshot of the basic project setup:

[image: project setup]

dllmain.h

```cpp
#ifndef DLLMAIN_H_
#define DLLMAIN_H_

#ifdef FFMPEGLIB_EXPORTS
#define FFMPEGLIB_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define FFMPEGLIB_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif // FFMPEGLIB_EXPORTS

static void TestFoo();

extern "C" FFMPEGLIB_API void Test(int* num);

extern "C" FFMPEGLIB_API void ProxyFoo();

#endif
```

dllmain.cpp

```cpp
#include "dllmain.h"
#include "A.h"

void TestFoo()
{
    A a;
    a.foo();
}

void Test(int* num)
{
    *num = *num + 1;
}

void ProxyFoo()
{
    TestFoo();
}
```

driver.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

#include "dllmain.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int mum  = 4;
    Test(&num);

    std::cout << num;

    ProxyFoo();

    return 0;
}
```

The library project compiles normally, but the exe fails to compile with a linker error:

[image: linker error]

```
Code        Description                                 Project     File
LNK2001     unresolved extern symbol _imp_ProxyFoo      driver      driver.obj
LNK2001     unresolved extern symbol _imp_Test          driver      driver.obj
LNK1120     2 unresolved externals                      driver      driver.exe
```

I have two questions here:

1. Why does the function name of `dllmain.h` get mangled in spite of being marked as `extern "C"`?
2. Why can I not create an instance of test class `A` from `extern` methods? What would be a good way of doing that?

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code.  Post the actual code and error messages.

Comment: @selbie Thanks for editing the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why the function name of dllmain.h getting mangled in spite being
> marked as extern "C"?

Because `__declspec(dllimport)`.

> Why can I not create instance of test class A from extern methods?
> What would be good way of doing it?

I think that's fine, but you didn't provide any `class A` code. Just do this:

```
class __declspec(dllexport) A
{
    /* ... */
};
```

> Why EXE compile failed?

This is because you have not imported the LIB file of the DLL into the project.

There are two ways to import it:

1. Add `#program comment(lib, "<YOUR_LIB_FILE>.lib")` to the code file.
2. Add `<YOUR_LIB_FILE>.lib` to Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies.

Microsoft documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/importing-and-exporting

Comment: So it's seems to be working now... with only one bit of change - defining static lib under the Linker -> input

Can you provide some reference on linking the dll without the static library

Comment: @uzer But this would be troublesome, because you would need to define the function type and get the address for each `extern "C"` exported function, which is almost impossible for exported C++ classes. Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/linking-an-executable-to-a-dll?view=msvc-160#how-to-link-explicitly-to-a-dll

Comment: Yes I looked into that approach and it seems bit convoluted for simple task... anyways thanks for clearing this out :)

Comment: In this case its not called a static library. It's an import library. Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3573475/how-does-the-import-library-work-details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3573475/how-does-the-import-library-work-details)

Answer (score -1):

You need to put the `extern "C"` thing around your function definitions that you intend to export in `dllmain.cpp` so it matches the linkage of your declaration.

Also, you need to do the `declexport` thing too.

```
extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) void Test(int* num)
    {
       *num = *num + 1;
    }

    __declspec(dllexport) void ProxyFoo()
    {
        TestFoo();
    }
}
```

Comment: Answer updated. You need to declexport them as well.

Comment: Applying the `extern "C"` and `__declspec(dllexport)` to the function *declarations* will suffice, they do not need to be applied to the function *definitions* as well.