# Why would a library consist of both a .lib and .dll file?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, dll, lib

I'm following the SDL [MSVC installation guide][1]. Specifically, I'm linking my project to the static libraries SDL2.lib and SDLmain.lib.

This guide states that the executable must have access to the SDL2.dll to run. Why is this necessary?

Why can't I just statically link my project to these libraries? Why do I need both the static library files (.lib) and dynamic link library files (.dll)?

Comment: Or maybe this one: [How does the Import Library work? Details?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3573475/10871073)

Comment: @AdrianMole Thanks, those do answer my question. That answer being: Microsoft is stupid for using the .lib file extension for two different things.