# how to add the reference of dll in a makefile for cpp project()

Tags: c++, dll, makefile

I need to add the reference to a "System.Management.Automation.dll" in my cpp project.
and to build this project there is the makefile.
I am new to makefiles and need to know how to add the reference of this dll in my existing makefile.

Answer (score 1):

Referencing a DLL is done by loading a DLL (dynamic linking in code). You do not need to state it in the makefile.

You might accually want to add a lib and includes for this DLL.

Refer to [this link (dll and lib distinction)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778111/whats-the-differences-between-dll-lib-h-files)

Comment: mrvoid what I am looking for is the way to reference the "System.Management.Automation.dll" in my project from the makefile as we do it from the visual studio.
In visual studio we can browse to the dll and then we can add it.
By loading a dll u meant the loadlibrary right? but this will not allow me to use the namespace as
using namespace System::Management::Automation;

Comment: To use the namespace you would have to use #include in cpp files so that the definitions for those namespaces are there.